# Firefox SVG with fill:url(#id) style in external stylesheet broken, inline styles are fine

Tags: html, firefox, svg

In Firefox only, if I try to give a svg path a pattern reference like:

path {
  fill: url(#ref);
}

in an external style sheet, it renders invisible. If I do it inline, or in a  tag on the page, it works.

Here is my fiddle, and here is my code dump because SO won't let me post just the fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/v5VDp/1/

```
    <pattern id="texture_base" x="0" y="0" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="122" width="213">
        <image x="0" y="0" width="213" height="122" xlink:href=""/>
    </pattern>

        <pattern id="texture1" x="0" y="0" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="122" width="213">
        <rect fill='url(#color1)' stroke="none" x="0" y="0" width="213" height="122"/> 
            <rect fill='url(#texture_base)' x="0" y="0" width="213" height="122"/ />

    </pattern>
</defs>
</svg>
```

.slice:nth-child(6n + 2) path {
    fill: url(#texture1);
}

https://dl.dropbox.com/s/wkzaoiwnw6ghsmd/simple_svg_test.css

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`#texture1` is short for `<url of this file>` + `#texturl`. So in an external stylesheet `#texture1` will point to something in the stylesheet itself which won't be found as the element is in the svg file.

Webkit has always got this wrong which causes much confusion. You should find Opera matches Firefox behaviour as does IE.

If you want to do this in the stylesheet you'd have to use an absolute URL e.g. url(http://jsfiddle.net/v5VDp/1/#texture1)

This is covered by the [CSS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#uri). You could always contact the [CSS working group and suggest that they do something about it](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/).

Comment: So how do I refer to the current dom in the external style sheet? That seems pretty counter intuitive

Comment: Them's the rules for CSS stylesheets. They weren't really written with SVG use cases in mind I guess.

Comment: I see you commenting on a lot of the firefox bugs filed around this case... I understand that the stylesheet spec says that is how you should reference urls, but you're basically forcing me to put any svg styles I might have inline on the page... seems like the compromise Chrome/webkit made is the logical one.

Comment: or at least give me an option to force it

Answer (score 3):

SVG “fill: url(#…)” behave strangely in Firefox when we assigning the below code with css(both external and internal css.)

```
#myselector {
fill: url('#gradient-id');
}
```

Solution

give inline styling, this can be done in both the ways. Static or dynamic way

Dynamic way

```
.attr('fill', 'url(#gradient-id)')
```

Static way

```
fill="url(#gradient-id)"
```

In static you have to put this in the SVG Html;

Comment: This works as well,Replacing the css code with the js.